# Is it possible to make WPF app mainwindow inaccessible from taskbar while showing taskbar icon?

Tags: wpf, windows

I have a WPF app which has mainwindow that hosts win32 content. When mainwindow is created I set

```
ShowInTaskbar = false
```

and locate it outside screen(s). When it's ready I set

```
ShowInTaskbar = true
```

This however causes taskbar icon to be changed to Citrix default icon when run in XenApp Citrix.

So my question is: Can I show the taskbar icon all the time for the app in a way that user can not see/access the mainwindow via taskbar icon?

Comment: A compromise would be to make the icon available in the TrayBar (where the clock is on Windows), and control it from there, using a ContextMenu.

Comment: thanks @LupuSilviu! good idea, but try to solve it some other way. the best way would be not to hide taskbar icon at all.